# Is there a unified syntax for element-wise in-place operations on scalars and arrays in Julia?

Tags: performance, julia, allocation, in-place

Consider the following accumulator type, which works like an array in that you can push things to it, but only tracks its mean:

```
mutable struct Accumulator{T}
    data::T
    count::Int64
end

function Base.push!(acc::Accumulator, term)
    acc.data += term       # <-- in-place addition
    acc.count += 1
    acc
end

mean(acc::Accumulator) = acc.data ./ acc.count
```

I want this to work for `T` being a scalar or an array type. However,
it turns out that for `T` being an array type, the addition in `push!` creates a temporary.  This is because in Julia, `x+=a` is [equivalent](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/249) to `x=x+a`, and I suspect Julia cannot guarantee that `acc.data` and `term` do not alias.

A simple fix is to replace `+=` with element-wise addition, `.+=`. However, this will then break scalar types, which do not allow this.  So the only way I came up with to fix this problem is to add a specialization of the following form:

```
function Base.push!(acc::Accumulator, term::AbstractArray)
    acc.data .+= term       # <-- element-wise addition
    acc.count += 1
    acc
end
```

This is however somewhat ugly and also brittle... does anyone know a better way of doing this, preferrably in a generic fashion and without the temporary creation?

Comment: There might be a more elegant answer than my answer below that makes use of [iterator traits](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-iteration) such as  `IteratorSize` and `IteratorEltype`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an approach that uses iterator traits to generically handle the different possible scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddly enough, [`Number`s are iterable in Julia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7903), but that doesn't seem to help us here, because there is no `setindex!` method for `Number`s.

Here are two different approaches. The first uses [iterator traits](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-iteration) and the second just patches up the method signatures a bit to address corner cases.

### Iterator traits

We can use the `IteratorSize` trait to distinguish between scalars and vectors. For scalars, `Base.IteratorSize(x)` returns `Base.HasShape{0}`. For arrays, `Base.IteratorSize(x)` returns `Base.HasShape{N}`, where `N` is the number of dimensions of the array.

```
mutable struct Accumulator{T}
    data::T
    count::Int64
end

function Base.push!(acc::Accumulator{T}, term::S) where {T, S}
    _push_acc!(Base.IteratorSize(T), Base.IteratorSize(S), acc, term)
end

function _push_acc!(::Base.HasShape{0}, ::Base.HasShape{0}, acc::Accumulator, term)
    acc.data += term
    acc.count += 1
    acc
end

function _push_acc!(::Base.HasShape{N}, ::Base.HasShape{N}, acc::Accumulator, term) where {N}
    acc.data .+= term
    acc.count += 1
    acc
end

function _push_acc!(::Base.HasShape{M}, ::Base.HasShape{N}, ::Accumulator, ::Any) where {M, N}
    throw(ArgumentError("Accumulator and term have inconsistent shapes"))
end
```

In action at the REPL:

```js
julia> a = Accumulator(1, 0)
Accumulator{Int64}(1, 0)

julia> b = Accumulator([1, 2], 0)
Accumulator{Array{Int64,1}}([1, 2], 0)

julia> push!(a, 42)
Accumulator{Int64}(43, 1)

julia> push!(b, [3, 4])
Accumulator{Array{Int64,1}}([4, 6], 1)

julia> push!(a, [5, 6])
ERROR: ArgumentError: Accumulator and term have inconsistent shapes
Stacktrace:
 [1] _push_acc!(::Base.HasShape{0}, ::Base.HasShape{1}, ::Accumulator{Int64}, ::Array{Int64,1}) at ...
 [2] push!(::Accumulator{Int64}, ::Array{Int64,1}) at ...
 [3] top-level scope at REPL[6]:1

julia> push!(b, 10)
ERROR: ArgumentError: Accumulator and term have inconsistent shapes
Stacktrace:
 [1] _push_acc!(::Base.HasShape{1}, ::Base.HasShape{0}, ::Accumulator{Array{Int64,1}}, ::Int64) at ...
 [2] push!(::Accumulator{Array{Int64,1}}, ::Int64) at ...
 [3] top-level scope at REPL[7]:1
```

### Patching the method signatures

Instead of using iterator traits, we could just make a couple small tweaks to your `push!` method signatures to prevent pushing an array onto a scalar.

```
mutable struct Accumulator{T}
    data::T
    count::Int64
end

function Base.push!(acc::Accumulator, term)
    acc.data += term
    acc.count += 1
    acc
end

function Base.push!(acc::Accumulator{T}, term::AbstractArray) where {T <: AbstractArray}
    acc.data .+= term
    acc.count += 1
    acc
end

function Base.push!(::Accumulator, ::AbstractArray)
    throw(ArgumentError("Can't push an array onto a scalar"))
end
```

Now we get a sensible error message if we try to push an array onto a scalar:

```js
julia> a = Accumulator(42, 0)
Accumulator{Int64}(42, 0)

julia> push!(a, [1, 2])
ERROR: ArgumentError: Can't push an array onto a scalar
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and catching the important corner case!  I would like to leave this question open for a little bit in case someone comes up with something generic, especially something that works with general "iterable" objects.  As a tangent: Who in the nine circles of hell has decided that it is a remotely acceptable idea to make numbers iterable?!?

Comment: I haven't followed the issue closely, but here's [one argument in favor of iterable numbers](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/11769#issuecomment-113686716). Of course that comment is 5 years old now, so maybe things have changed.